# WIFI is not working even after driver install 16.04.2 Server LTS

Tags: wireless, server

I have set it up as dhcp to test if working:
Output:

```
$ sudo ifdown wlp3s0 && sudo ifup -v wlp3s0
ifdown: interface wlp3s0 not configured
Configuring interface wlp3s0=wlp3s0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ IF_BOND_SLAVES=
+ [  ]
+ [  ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exit
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vlan
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools

/sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlp3s0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlp3s0.leases -I -df     /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient6.wlp3s0.leases wlp3s0 
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlp3s0/80:e6:50:29:1a:3a
Sending on   LPF/wlp3s0/80:e6:50:29:1a:3a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x405f0745)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x405f0745)
DHCPDISCOVER on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x405f0745)
...OMITTED!!!!
...
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ifenslave
+ [ inet = meta ]
+ [  ]
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/ip
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
```

Please see other wifi information:

```
$ iwconfig
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management: off

lo        no wireless extensions.

ens9      no wireless extensions.
```

On my router the configuration for wireless:

```
Security: WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK
WIFI PASSWORD (security key) tempest123
WIFI Network Name (SSID) VM1234567
```

Output on /etc/network/interfaces

```
  GNU nano 2.5.3                        File: /etc/network/interfaces                                                        

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens9
iface ens9 inet dhcp
# WIFI
auto wlp3s0
iface wlp3s0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid VM1234567
wpa-psk tempest123
```

Please let me know what other outputs do you need in order for this to be troubleshooted?

I tried, reboot, removed the config and put back again.  Re-installed the driver as well.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

eve@Eve:~$ lspci -k | grep -i Ethernet -A3
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

I have rebooted the server, and dhcp is trying to get an IP, then it times out after 5 mins and boots to ubuntu without IP connectivity.

I have already done sudo apt upgrade and update on this server as well.

Please let me know what else I need to do?

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -k | grep -i Ethernet -A3`, `ip link` and `rfkill list`.

Comment: @Hölderlin, I have edited my question with the command outputs that you requested.

Comment: Where is your Wirelesscard connected via PCI or USB, because it's not listed in `lspci` so try `lspci -k | grep -i net -A3`? Best you would tidy up the question and post the output of those [wireless analysis script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) instead  your current code snippets.

Comment: The output is in this 
[link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25027235/)

Comment: For me it seems you using the correct driver and connected to the router via wlan. It's different as before, so did you installed the driver or already tried to reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dkms bcmwl-kernel-source`? Do you have internet access now? Did you also tried to connect to your access point using [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant), it could manage your configurations. And AFAIK your blacklist looks fine.